# CSS sidebars not showing up

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a very very simple template. Or so I thought. The template didn't originally come with sidebars so I tried to sneak them in there myself. It's not working at all- I don't see my test text show up at all.

Can someone please point me to what I did wrong?

You can see the page in question at http://www.stfuisland.com/add.html

The code is posted below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>STFU Island</title>
<style type="text/css">

a.header:link {
color:#ffffff;
text-decoration:none;
hover {color:#ffcc00;}
}

body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
overflow: hidden;
height: 100%; 
max-height: 100%; 
}

#framecontent{
position: absolute; 
top: 0; 
left: 0; 
width: 100%; 
height: 70px; /*Height of frame div*/
overflow: hidden; /*Disable scrollbars. Set to "scroll" to enable*/
background-color: navy;
color: white;
}


#maincontent{    
position: fixed; 
top: 75px; /*Set top value to HeightOfFrameDiv*/
//left: 0;
//right: 0;
bottom: 0;
overflow: auto; 
background: #fff;
}

#leftbar {
float: left;
width: 30%;
}

#rightbar {
float: right;
width: 30%;
}
.innertube{
margin: 15px; /*Margins for inner DIV inside each DIV (to provide padding)*/
}

* html body{ /*IE6 hack*/
padding: 130px 0 0 0; /*Set value to (HeightOfFrameDiv 0 0 0)*/
}    

* html #maincontent{ /*IE6 hack*/
height: 100%; 
width: 100%; 
}

</style>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="leftbar">
<div class="innertube">
<p>test</p>
</div></div>

<body>
<div id="rightbar">
<div class="innertube">
<p>test</p>
</div></div>

<div id="framecontent">
<div class="innertube">


<center><h3><font color="white"><a class="header" href="index.html">home</a> | <a href="islandstatus.html">Are You on an Island?</a> | <a href="about.html">About</a></font></h1></center>

</div>
</div>

<div id="maincontent">
<div class="innertube">
<center>
<form class="pure-form">
<fieldset class="pure-group">
    <input type="text" class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="Your Name" name="creatorname" size="50">
    <input type="text" class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="Your Email" name="creatoremail">
    <input type="email" class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="Relationship to people being sent to island" name="relationship">
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="pure-group">
    <input type="text" class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="Name of first person sent to STFU Island" name="person1">
    <input type="text" class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="Their email address" name="email1">
</fieldset>


<fieldset class="pure-group">
    <input type="text" class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="Name of second person sent to STFU Island" name="person2">
    <input type="text" class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="Their email address" name="email2">
</fieldset>


<fieldset class="pure-group">
    <input type="text" class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="Name of third person sent to STFU Island" name="person3">
    <input type="text" class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="Their email address" name="email3">
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="pure-group">
    <input type="text" class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="Tell them why they're being sent to STFU Island!" cols="40" rows="5" name="reason">
</fieldset>


<button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary" name="submit">Send them to STFU Island!</button>
<br>aaaaEmail addresses are sacred and we will treat them that way. Email addresses collected are only used to send emails when people are added or are being set free from STFU island. No other company will ever see or use them for any reason. Period.
</form>

</center>


</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems to be showing me text and working correctly for me in Chrome 31

Comment: the bars are actually there, they're just under your header.  You may need to add a height to them

Comment: Just some constructive criticism: You have multiple `<body>` tags, and you should not use the old style tags like `<center>` and `<font>`, they are deprecated. Styling should all be done via CSS

Comment: Hi Pete, How do I add a height to the side bars so they don't overlap with the header bar?

Answer (score 1):

Add to your CSS: (for #leftbar and #rightbar)

```
z-index: 2;
position: relative;
```

That works for me, also you might want to use color:#fff so you can see it.
Use text-align:center instead of center,
Use 1 div instead of multiple divs inside each other..

The source is very busy and messy; too messy for something which is pretty simple.
I'll make a clone which shows how simplified it can be and update later.

Comment: Thanks Oscar. That got my text to show up! Only problem now is the text is overlapping on the top banner part. Is there an easy change to make it appear under the header?

Comment: @AaronAnderson You would have to add `position:absolute; top:70px;` and then add `left:0` to your left side bar and `right:0` to your right side bar. At this point you can remove your `float` on both side bars.

Comment: Sorry for the wait Aaron. http://jsfiddle.net/uB992/ Redid it, that's a lot more simplified. If you want to specify the form theme a bit more, I would happily help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your left side bar and right side bar are underneath your title. I imagine you want them inside the maincontent and next to your innertube. moving your divs next to the inner tube will show up in the layout you want.

```
<div id="leftbar">
   ...
</div>
<div class="innertube">
   ...
</div>
<div id="rightbar">
  ...
</div>
```

also add a float: left to your inner tube

Answer (score 0):

Your header is `position: absolute`, which takes it out of the normal flow and hides your sidebars.

A typical three column layout with header and footer might look like

HTML

```
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="nav left">Left Navigation</div>
    <div class="nav right">Right Navigation</div>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

CSS

```
.nav {
    background: green;
    width: 100px;
}

.nav.left {
    float: left;
}

.nav.right {
    float: right;
}

.content {
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
```

See full [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uf7gZ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your codes, I can't quite tell what you are after. Is it a three column layout with left and right bars and middle content has framecontent on top and maincontent at the bottom OR left bar | framecontent | right bar and have maincontent sitting under all three?

If you are trying to achieve a basic 3-column layout, there really is no need to have that div with a width of 100% plus an absolute position. The result will be the div sitting on top of the left and right bars.

just float left bar to the left (float:left), float the middle content to left as well and float the right content to right, and you will have 3 column layout. If you want both framecontent and maincontent to sit in the middle, then you can put maincontent inside the framecontent div.

I hope my explanation is not too confusing.